# A Cauchy-Schwarz-type inequality for positive definite kernels

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $K : \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive definite kernel, and suppose $K \geq 0$. I was wondering if there were any conditions we can impose on points $x, y, a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that:
\begin{equation}
K(x,y) K(a,a) \geq K(x,a) K(y,a)
\end{equation}
holds.

I know that if $x=y$, then this always holds, by the usual Cauchy-Schwarz-type inequality for p.d. kernels.

I have also noticed that, if $K(a,a) = 1$ for all $a$, then it is sufficient to impose that $d(x,y):= -\ln(K(x,y))$ is a metric; the identity then follows by taking logs and using the triangle inequality.

For example, when $K(x,y) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}||x-y||^2)$ is the Gaussian kernel, the identity holds if and only if $(x-a) \cdot (y-a) \geq 0$. This can be interpreted geometrically as $x$ and $y$ being on the 'same side' of $a$. That is, $y$ is in the half-space containing $x$ whose boundary is perpendicular to $x-a$.

Although the case where $K(x,y) = K(x-y)$ is interesting, I also wonder if there is anything we can say more generally.